# Using GPU capabilities for retraining images using retrain.py on tensorflow-hub

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-hub

I am new to Tensorflow, I am using retrain.py to train some images. In case I have a larger data base of 10000 images and I have a GPU capable system. How can i use retrain.py to run on my Nvidia GPU. So that training will be done faster.

I am following the steps from the link below

**https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining**

Answer (score 0):

To get GPU support, be sure to install the PIP package tensorflow-gpu instead of plain tensorflow. You should see some performance benefits from that for retrain.py. That said, retrain.py shows its age (far predating TF Hub) and does not utilize GPUs so well, because it does not properly batch images when extracting bottleneck values.

If you are ready to live on the cutting edge of TF 2.0.0alpha0 ([announced](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQY2H8rRoyvzoUYI26kHmKSJBedn3SQuB) last week), take a look at Hub's
[examples/colab/tf2_image_retraining.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_image_retraining.ipynb) which is considerably smaller, faster (**if** you use a GPU), and even supports fine-tuning the image module.